# How about Responsive Web Design nowadays

Tags: responsive-design, responsive

guys.

I'm revisiting some topics about RWD and all I have found about this was written two or three years ago. Apparently, there are no big changes but I'd like to discuss RWD nowadays to increase my skills on this.

Thanks!

Comment: The only innovation on RWD is CSS Grid: https://alistapart.com/article/practical-grid

Comment: This question will eventually be closed as it's off topic. StackOverflow is for addressing specific problems (with code) and not a discussion board.

Comment: I'm just starting to use StackOverflow, @hungerstar. But you're totally right, sorry.